# Set template in html after changes

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a next a method how compile and set in DOM my html:

```
export function initHTMLOperator(container) {
    if (container.template) {
        const template =  SF.handlebars.compile(container.template);
        const html = template(container);
        const elem = document.getElementsByTagName(container.id)[0];
        elem.innerHTML = html; // set compiled template
    }
}
```

`container.template` has a template
`container` - it is object with variables for template.

After compilation I set html in DOM.

But i have a problem when changing input i recompile template and losing focus.

Is it possible to update a template in the DOM without innerHTML?
I mean update template but not set full html, only changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like react and not handlebars then, you should use a virtual DOM and apply only changes, but handlebars doesn't provide such functionality. So no if you want your new template then you have to replace the whole content with something like innerHTML. But if the only problem is loosing your focus you can save it before replacing your content and reset the focus once the template has been replaced.

Comment: handlebars uses in Ember but it have dynamic render and as I understand with virtual dom?

Comment: Yes but then you have to use node.js and not pure html. For now you're using only pure html right ?